# Linux ssh output of two commands in an input

Tags: linux, ssh

I am looking for a command that will let me look for an rpm installed in my machine and remove it, the only information about the rpm to delete that I have is a suffix of its name, that's what I want to do in one command:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i $rpmnameSuffix >> output
rpm -e output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command substitution to substitute the output of a command into another command line.

```
rpm -e "$(rpm -qa | grep -i $rpmnameSuffix)"
```